# Hosting a legacy WebAPI without IIS for testing

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-web-api2, owin, devops

I am trying to find options for testing a .NET 4.6.2 WebAPI application that is hosted on IIS in production, but without hosting it as such during a test run.

I know that this can be done using OWIN implementations, many of which appear to require code changes and references to specific libraries. Because of organizational constraints, I need to seek alternatives which do not require any significant modifications to the application code or reliance on any 3rd party libraries.

I have also been lead to believe that "containers" as they are called (e.g. Docker) can by used for such, but have yet to find documentation which makes it clear if/how this can be used for pre-.NET Core applications.

So my question put simply is: can Docker (or similar product) be used to host a legacy WebAPI application without making code changes to said application, in such a way that test automation can be run against the endpoints?

Comment: Why can't you host it in IIS for testing? If you host it on a different platform than how it is hosted in production, then how valuable is your test? Sure the code works in the test environment, but since the configuration is different from production, then the test won't truly tell us that it won't break when deployed to production. This could possibly be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: OWIN isn't going to require code changes, just some added code to host your site.

Comment: @LewsTherin In my case, my only concern is testing application logic. The configuration testing will be handled in a subsequent step of the deployment pipeline.

Comment: @Maxx Then why not just run it in the Local IIS that comes installed with Visual Studio?

Comment: @BobProvencher The examples I've been able to find start with installing of packages as a prerequisite to OWIN hosting. I'd like to avoid having to add new dependencies of any kind to the solution. But then, the only documentation I've been able to find is several years old and may not reflect currently available implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, unfortunately, no. If it would work, it would only be because the Docker image had IIS in it.

There are no shortcuts here. Either use OWIN, or switch entirely to DotNet Core, or use IIS everywhere.

Given the constraints you have hinted at, I would guess that getting IIS everywhere is your most likely solution.

But try to convince your manager that Core is the future and that the time spent on the upgrade is definitely worth it.

(Running on Core in Docker is a valid solution.)

Comment: Docker image with IIS might be exactly what I want. If doing so would not require any files to be added to the source code repo, then it would be preferable to OWIN implementations that require extra files for configuration to be inside the solution directory.